# Passing javac arguments in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

In my maven compiler plugin I have the following setting:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
   <configuration>
     <source>${java.version}</source>
     <target>${java.version}</target>
     <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Is there a way to pass the `-parameters` part to the compiler used by eclipse?

Comment: Does in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ checking the _Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)_ checkbox fix your issue?

Comment: The checkbox should be checked automatically (see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518218)). Maybe you are using an outdated version of Eclipse.

Comment: Does [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html) help?

Comment: @howlger thanks, this is it. But I cannot accept comments. Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***Project > Properties: Java Compiler*** you have to check the ***Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)*** checkbox for that.

The checkbox should be checked automatically (see fixed [Eclipse bug 518218](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518218)). If you are using an outdated version of Eclipse, please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).